# How to avoid TP being fired with SL, if TP has not yet been reached?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

The script sends messages to the broker for each action. Therefore to avoid errors, a TP order can not fire when an SL order does.

I'd be extremely grateful for any concrete examples with the code below, on how to have TP fire only if it reaches target, otherwise have SL close entire (or remaining position) by itself.

I tried various strategy.order combinations but I just can not get my head around this one.

```
//@version=5
//©duronic12 
strategy('TP/STOP ISSUE', overlay=true, max_bars_back=5000, process_orders_on_close=true)


    // MANAGE RISK 

tradeDirection = input.string(title='Trade Direction', options=['Long', 'Short', 'Both'], defval='Long', group='Risk Management')
longOK = tradeDirection == 'Long' or tradeDirection == 'Both'
shortOK = tradeDirection == 'Short' or tradeDirection == 'Both'
stopPer = input(2.0, title='SL (%)', group='Risk Management') / 100
bep = input(4.0, title='Move SL to Breakeven (%)', group='Risk Management')
takePer = input(6.0, title='TP (%)', group='Risk Management') / 100
qt = input(50.0, title='% to close on TP', group='Risk Management')
closeTC = input(true,"Trail after TP", group='Risk Management')
////


    // ENTER

HPeriod = 13
LPeriod = 21
hsma = 0.0
lsma = 0.0
hsma := ta.sma(high, HPeriod)
lsma := ta.sma(low, LPeriod)
iff_1 = close < nz(lsma[1]) ? -1 : 0
HLd = close > nz(hsma[1]) ? 1 : iff_1
HLv = ta.valuewhen(HLd != 0, HLd, 0)
HiLo = HLv == -1 ? hsma : lsma
HLcolor = HLv == -1 ? color.maroon : color.blue
plot(HiLo, title="Entry/Trail", linewidth=1, color=HLcolor)

enterLong = (HLv == 1 and HLv[1] == -1)
enterShort = (HLv == -1 and HLv[1] == 1)

if longOK and enterLong
    strategy.entry(id='EL', comment='BUY', direction=strategy.long)
if shortOK and enterShort
    strategy.entry(id='ES', comment='SELL', direction=strategy.short)
////


    // EXIT 

longStop = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - stopPer)
shortStop = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + stopPer)
shortTake = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - takePer)
longTake = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + takePer)
shortTake1 = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - (99/100))

ExitSell()=>
    (bar_index - strategy.closedtrades.exit_bar_index(strategy.closedtrades-1)) == 0 and strategy.position_size[1]<0
ExitBuy()=>
    (bar_index - strategy.closedtrades.exit_bar_index(strategy.closedtrades-1)) == 0 and strategy.position_size[1]>0
EntryBuy()=>
    (strategy.opentrades > 0 ? (bar_index - strategy.opentrades.entry_bar_index(strategy.opentrades-1)) : na) == 1 and strategy.position_size>0
EntrySell()=>
    (strategy.opentrades > 0 ? (bar_index - strategy.opentrades.entry_bar_index(strategy.opentrades-1)) : na) == 1 and strategy.position_size<0

H = ta.highest(high,nz(ta.barssince(EntryBuy()),1)+1)
L = ta.lowest(low,nz(ta.barssince(EntrySell()),1)+1)

profit = strategy.position_size>0?((H-strategy.position_avg_price)/strategy.position_avg_price)*100:strategy.position_size<0?((L-strategy.position_avg_price)/strategy.position_avg_price)*-100:na

SL_long = profit>=bep?strategy.position_avg_price:longStop
SL_short = profit>=bep?strategy.position_avg_price:shortStop

plot_sl1 = plot(strategy.position_size>0?SL_long:na,"Long SL",color=color.orange,linewidth=1,style=plot.style_linebr)
plot_sl2 = plot(strategy.position_size<0?SL_short:na,"Short SL",color=color.orange,linewidth=1,style=plot.style_linebr)

//Partial Exit via Take Profit
if strategy.position_size > 0
    strategy.exit(id='TP', qty_percent=qt, stop=SL_long, limit=longTake)
if strategy.position_size < 0
    strategy.exit(id='TP', qty_percent=qt, stop=SL_short, limit=shortTake)

//Full Exit via Stop Loss  
if strategy.position_size > 0
    strategy.exit(id='SL', qty_percent=100, stop=SL_long, limit=longTake*1000)
if strategy.position_size < 0
    strategy.exit(id='SL', qty_percent=100, stop=SL_short, limit=shortTake1)

//Full Exit via Trailing Stop 
if profit>=(takePer*100) and strategy.position_size > 0 and HLv == -1 and closeTC
    strategy.close('EL',comment='TSL')
if profit>=(takePer*100) and strategy.position_size < 0 and HLv == 1 and closeTC
    strategy.close('ES',comment='TSL')
////
```

Comment: I think there are missing some info about alert settings for this strategy. Do you create the alert with webhook for this strategy? Or the problem can be shown on a chart too?

Comment: Hi Andrey, thanks for taking a look. Yes the problem can be seen on the chart. Once solved I will include alert_message to send via webhook.

Comment: Could you please attach the screenshot demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Absolutey. Here you go - https://www.tradingview.com/x/N2XvGICs/ ...I tried using "strategy.order('SL', strategy.short,  stop=SL_long, oca_name='L', oca_type=strategy.oca.cancel)" for the SL, and this seemed to work in some instances, but created issues elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your code. Try it:

```
//@version=5
//©duronic12 
strategy('TP/STOP ISSUE', overlay=true, max_bars_back=5000, process_orders_on_close=true)


    // MANAGE RISK 

tradeDirection = input.string(title='Trade Direction', options=['Long', 'Short', 'Both'], defval='Long', group='Risk Management')
longOK = tradeDirection == 'Long' or tradeDirection == 'Both'
shortOK = tradeDirection == 'Short' or tradeDirection == 'Both'
stopPer = input(2.0, title='SL (%)', group='Risk Management') / 100
bep = input(4.0, title='Move SL to Breakeven (%)', group='Risk Management')
takePer = input(6.0, title='TP (%)', group='Risk Management') / 100
qt = input(50.0, title='% to close on TP', group='Risk Management')
closeTC = input(true,"Trail after TP", group='Risk Management')
////


    // ENTER

HPeriod = 13
LPeriod = 21
hsma = 0.0
lsma = 0.0
hsma := ta.sma(high, HPeriod)
lsma := ta.sma(low, LPeriod)
iff_1 = close < nz(lsma[1]) ? -1 : 0
HLd = close > nz(hsma[1]) ? 1 : iff_1
HLv = ta.valuewhen(HLd != 0, HLd, 0)
HiLo = HLv == -1 ? hsma : lsma
HLcolor = HLv == -1 ? color.maroon : color.blue
plot(HiLo, title="Entry/Trail", linewidth=1, color=HLcolor)

enterLong = (HLv == 1 and HLv[1] == -1)
enterShort = (HLv == -1 and HLv[1] == 1)

if longOK and enterLong
    strategy.entry(id='EL', comment='BUY', direction=strategy.long)
if shortOK and enterShort
    strategy.entry(id='ES', comment='SELL', direction=strategy.short)
////


    // EXIT 

longStop = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - stopPer)
shortStop = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + stopPer)
shortTake = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - takePer)
longTake = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + takePer)
shortTake1 = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - (99/100))

ExitSell()=>
    (bar_index - strategy.closedtrades.exit_bar_index(strategy.closedtrades-1)) == 0 and strategy.position_size[1]<0
ExitBuy()=>
    (bar_index - strategy.closedtrades.exit_bar_index(strategy.closedtrades-1)) == 0 and strategy.position_size[1]>0
EntryBuy()=>
    (strategy.opentrades > 0 ? (bar_index - strategy.opentrades.entry_bar_index(strategy.opentrades-1)) : na) == 1 and strategy.position_size>0
EntrySell()=>
    (strategy.opentrades > 0 ? (bar_index - strategy.opentrades.entry_bar_index(strategy.opentrades-1)) : na) == 1 and strategy.position_size<0

H = ta.highest(high,nz(ta.barssince(EntryBuy()),1)+1)
L = ta.lowest(low,nz(ta.barssince(EntrySell()),1)+1)

profit = if strategy.position_size>0
    ((H-strategy.position_avg_price)/strategy.position_avg_price)*100
else if strategy.position_size<0
    ((L-strategy.position_avg_price)/strategy.position_avg_price)*-100
else
    na

SL_long = profit>=bep?strategy.position_avg_price:longStop
SL_short = profit>=bep?strategy.position_avg_price:shortStop

plot_sl1 = plot(strategy.position_size>0?SL_long:na,"Long SL",color=color.orange,linewidth=1,style=plot.style_linebr)
plot_sl2 = plot(strategy.position_size<0?SL_short:na,"Short SL",color=color.orange,linewidth=1,style=plot.style_linebr)

isFlipped(a, b)=>
// from short/flat to long     from flat/long to short
    (a <= 0 and b > 0)     or    (a >= 0 and b < 0)

// returns abs position size after open and 0 if there is no open position or existing position partially closed
absPositionSizeAfterLastEntryBeforeAnyExit()=>
    var float result = 0
    if isFlipped(strategy.position_size[1], strategy.position_size)
        result := math.abs(strategy.position_size)
    else if math.abs(strategy.position_size) < result // some exit executed
        result := 0
    result
    

curPosSize = absPositionSizeAfterLastEntryBeforeAnyExit()
if curPosSize > 0
    fullQty = curPosSize
    partialQty = fullQty * qt / 100
    // Exits
    if strategy.position_size > 0
        strategy.order('TP', strategy.short, qty=partialQty, limit=longTake, oca_name="exit_long", oca_type = strategy.oca.reduce)
        strategy.order('SL', strategy.short, qty=fullQty, stop=SL_long, oca_name="exit_long", oca_type = strategy.oca.reduce)
    else if strategy.position_size < 0
        strategy.order('TP', strategy.long, qty=partialQty, limit=shortTake, oca_name="exit_short", oca_type = strategy.oca.reduce)
        strategy.order('SL', strategy.long, qty=fullQty, stop=SL_short, oca_name="exit_short", oca_type = strategy.oca.reduce)

if strategy.position_size == 0
    strategy.cancel('TP')
    strategy.cancel('SL')
    
//Full Exit via Trailing Stop 
if profit>=(takePer*100) and strategy.position_size > 0 and HLv == -1 and closeTC
    strategy.close('EL',comment='TSL')
if profit>=(takePer*100) and strategy.position_size < 0 and HLv == 1 and closeTC
    strategy.close('ES',comment='TSL')
////ZILUSDT
```

Comment: Andrey, thanks so much. Really appreciate your effort.

It's almost perfect, but now the breakeven sl (bep) is not being respected?

Yesterday (using default settings and LONG),  the SL (orange line) moved to breakeven as per inputs, but the strategy stopped out at the entry stop price, not the new adjusted/breakeven value as before https://s3.tradingview.com/snapshots/k/kTTHXuZC.png

Comment: Oooops ) The code was updated.

Comment: Andrey, you legend! Thank you so much for your time and effort on this. Really appreciate. I had been banging my head at the wall for weeks trying to get it working  

Comment: After more testing, it seems to work perfectly if just going long or short, but when both is selected, it misbehaves... See here, it should of taken profit and closed on trail but nothing happened. https://ibb.co/xf1KtWM

Comment: Hey Andrey, hope all is well. Just wondering if you know how to fix the issue of it not working correctly when set to Both? Happy to hire you. Not having much luck in chat groups and hiring on fiverr and upwork. Seems scripts involving strategy.order are just out of most peoples wheelhouse.

Comment: i've tried to open https://ibb.co/xf1KtWM and it said "page is not exists" .

Comment: Here you go Andrey. This is the original vs your edit set to LONG (no errors) - https://www.tradingview.com/x/vXvlSNm8/. This is the original vs your edit set to BOTH - https://www.tradingview.com/x/OBcYCuFE/ (no SL or TP being taken on your edit).

Comment: If I understood you issue correctly the last version with `Both` input hasn't any exits by TP or SL? If it is true, check the updated version.